# SQL join columns of two tables on unique key

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assume I have two tables, A and B, both with a unique key looking as follows (there are of course more rows and columns in the real table):

```
Unique_Key       A        B
____________________________
    ABC          1        2
    BCD          5        6
    DDD          10       11


 Unique_Key      C        D
____________________________
    ABC          6        7
    BCD          8        9
    DDD          100      200
```

I would like to join the columns of the two table on the `Unique_Key` to product the following output:

```
Unique_Key       A        B         C         D
_________________________________________________
    ABC          1        2         6         7
    BCD          5        6         8         9
    DDD          10       11        100       200
```

I have tried this:

```
select 
    [A], [C]
from 
    tableA r with (nolock) join tableB l with (nolock) on r.Unique_Key = 
l.Unique_Key
```

It works in so much as it does combine the table but it produces duplicate rows and I am not sure why. That is in essence what I want to avoid - to have duplicate rows.

Thanks!

Comment: The dataset provided doesn't have any duplicate unique_key. If you are getting dup keys, that means that the tables have duplicate unique_keys. Otherwise, there is nothing wrong with your query. Weed out the duplicates and use the join, it should run fine.

Comment: @SanMu  . . . Provide appropriate sample data that produces duplicate results and be clear on what results  you really want in that case.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the Join Command which works well in this case.

```
SELECT A.Unique_Key, A.Atable_Column1, A.Atable_Column2, B.Btable_Column3, B.Btable_Column4 
From Table1 A  inner join Table2 B
 on A.Unique_Key = B.Unique_Key
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use group by with aggregation

```
select 
    r.Unique_Key,max([A]), max([C])
from 
    tableA r join tableB l on r.Unique_Key = 
l.Unique_Key
group by r.Unique_Key
```

Answer (score 0):

If `unique_key` is really unique in each table, then this will do what you want without producing duplicates:

```
select r.unique_key, r.a, r.b, l.c, l.d
from tableA r join
     tableB l 
     on r.Unique_Key = l.Unique_Key;
```

If you are getting duplicates, your key is not unique.  You can identify the keys with duplicates by running:

```
select unique_key
from tableA r
group by unique_key
having count(*) > 1;
```

and:

```
select unique_key
from tableB l
group by unique_key
having count(*) > 1;
```

Based on your choice of names, you probably need to fix the underlying data.

Answer (score 0):

Neither `tableA.A` nor `tableB.C` is unique, or so I understand this.

With

```
Unique_Key | A | B
-----------+---+--
AAA        | 1 | 1
BBB        | 1 | 2
CCC        | 2 | 3
```

and

```
Unique_Key | C | D
-----------+---+--
AAA        | 1 | 1
BBB        | 1 | 2
CCC        | 4 | 5
```

you'd get

```
A | C
--+--
1 | 1
1 | 1
2 | 4
```

where you want

```
A | C
--+--
1 | 1
2 | 4
```

Use `DISTINCT` for that:

```
select distinct tablea.a, tableb.c
from tablea 
join tableb on tablea.unique_key = tableb.unique_key;
```